# Compare if lines contain phrase (regex with /n or multi-lines?)

Tags: bash, text, grep

Ive been wresteling with this for a few days now, and cant come up with a good solution (or really even the tools to use to move forward).

I have around 5k lines (in a txt file) like this:

***EDIT- I FORGOT TO ADD that some lines DO have spaces and singlequotes /apostrophes , so i have revised the sample set below. (the spaces were throwing off some of my earlier efforts,  will add this as comments-  sry about that)***

```
L:\folder7\video.1080p.disk.avi
L:\folder8\video3 cat 720p.img.mkv

L:\folder9\video.720p disk.avi
L:\folder0\video6.720p.img.mkv

L:\folder2\video's 1080p.disk.avi
L:\folder6\video2.1080p.img.mkv
```

line breaks are the delimiters, (or 2x line breaks (/n/n) are the delimiter i should say)

**My goal:**

```
if line1 contains 1080p and line2 contains 720p, then delete the 720p line (line2)
if line1 contains 1080p and line2 contains 1080p, then delete both lines
if line1 contains 1080p and line2 contains 1080p, then delete both lines

(and the reverse) 
if line1 contains 720p and line2 contains 1080p, then delete the 720p line (line1)
```

Im fine with breaking this up into manual operations by hand(ie via multiple manual grep/perl/notepad+++ > temp.txt runs) , as opposed to writing a if/elseif or Case , bash script to do it in one run.

Ive been struggling (and reading tons from google/here), on using line breaks with grep (even with -o or using tr '\n' ';' and later tr ';' '/n') Ive also had issues with using regex that works perfectly on regex101.com, but fails with egrep or perl.

can anyone offer some suggestions or point me in the right direction?  thanks

---

**edit/final: see my selected answer for explanation**,  for those wondering this is the final awk i used (my input was a .txt file from a windows app called "Duplicate Movie Finder for Plex", with ~5k lines),  this great awk compares /n/n delimited lines or entries, and roughly chooses the lower quality filePath/duplicate movie.
I then take the output from this awk command, add Del "path" and run list through windows CMD (to delete the lower quality duplicate).
The { print $2 ; next } allows awk to stop further processing and print correct line, if it finds a h265 or hevc file (as i want to NOT delete those, ie: in the case where there are 2x 1080p lines but one is a hevc).  BTW THIS does require alot of manual verification before you add/run the Del command. (dont just copy/paste)

```
awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' '$1 ~ /265/ && $2 ~ /1080p/ { print $2 ; next } $1 ~ 
/1080p/ && $2 ~ /265/ { print $1 ; next } $1 ~ /HEVC/ && $2 ~ /1080p/ { print 
$2 ; next } $1 ~ /1080p/ && $2 ~ /HEVC/ { print $1 ; next } $1 ~ /1080p/ && 
$2 ~ /720p/ { print $2 } $1 ~ /720p/ && $2 ~ /1080p/ { print $1 } $1 ~ 
/1080p/ && $2 ~ /1080p/ { print $2 } $1 ~ /720p/ && $2 ~ /720p/ { print $1 }' 
plex_dups_v4.txt
```

Comment: `grep` works one line at a time. This will be easier to do with `awk`.

Comment: this should work assuming there is no spaces in any line `awk -v RS= '$1 ~ /1080p/ && $2 ~ /720p/{$2=""} $1 ~ /1080p/ && $2 ~ /1080p/{$1=$2=""} $1 ~ /720p/ && $2 ~ /1080p/{$1=""} {print $0}'`

Comment: If your whole file is made up of exactly 3-line (2+blank) records, you could use column to merge those 3 lines onto 1 line, then the grep, or more likely sed, rules would be easy.

Comment: thanks for the 3x quick replies,  pointing me in the direction of awk is a big help.  will start testing with that and update here.  I HAVE UPDATED the post,  as there ARE spaces in the file names in some cases.

Comment: Note that you could merge patterns to make your script simpler, e.g. `$1 ~ /265|HEVC/ && $2 ~ /1080p/ { print $2 ; next }` instead of two separate rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P... provided a good solution with awk. It can be adjusted to deal with spaces like this :

```
awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' '
    $1 ~ /1080p/ && $2 ~ /720p/ { print $1 ; next }
    $2 ~ /1080p/ && $1 ~ /720p/ { print $2 }
    ' input_file
```

You can also do it with sed :

```
sed -n '/^$/ d ; /720p/ { n ; /1080p/ p ; d } ; N ; /720p/ P' input_file
```

Comment: thanks,  this is what i have been using and its working after i added quite a few more lines to deal with different cases in the actual text/data.  -  one question,  is there anyway i can get awk to stop processing a line (and move to next line) on a match?  Id like it to stop when IF it matches 265 (and print $2 but not go any further) -  here is what i copy/pasted together: (ignore ideone errors pls): https://ideone.com/e.js/GFu92C

Comment: Yes you can stop processing the current line and jump to the next one using the action `next`. Btw an early break after the first statement is better here, so I'll update the answer.

Comment: awesome,  thanks,  i have accepted this as the answer (and upvoted the others as i tried them and they worked mostly, but this was cleaner and worked fully IMO) -  one last question,  how would i make this ignore case?  (i have tried ignorecase=1, -v ignorecase=1, begin{..}  and using tolower($1) but couldn't get any to work with a test input.  thanks  (have updated OP with the final, full LONG awk im using).

Comment: Almost that to ignore the case, just use caps for the variable name, i.e. `-v IGNORECASE=1` on command line. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I would read three lines at a time :

```
while IFS='' read -r first_line; do
    IFS='' read -r second_line
    IFS='' read -r empty_line
    if [[ "$first_line" == *"1080p"* ]]; then
        if [[ "$second_line" == *"1080p"* ]]; then
            rm -- "$first_line" "$second_line" # both 1080p -> remove both
        else
            rm -- "$second_line" # first is 1080p, second is 720p -> remove second
        fi
    else
        if [[ "$second_line" == *"1080p"* ]]; then
            rm -- "$first_line" # first is 720p, second is 1080p -> remove first
        else
            rm -- "$first_line" "$second_line" # both 720p -> remove both (?)
        fi
    fi
done < yourInputFile
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/qvooHI).

Note that I assumed that files were either 720p or 1080p, if that's not the case you'll have to add `elif`s.

Comment: thanks-  *i have edited my orginal post, as there are spaces and single quotes at times in the files name*.  im not sure why the down vote from someone,  i did a fork, and as is it seemed to work with spaces and single quote / apostrophe.  im going to test it with more of my real data and will update with a link.  thanks again for writing all this!

Comment: No problem! Spaces shouldn't matter as the whole line is read into the single variable I specify to `read` and all subsequent references to the variables are properly quoted. Linefeeds in the filenames would be problematic of course, but any other character should be fine

Comment: Ah, the downvote might come from the fact I've interpreted your "remove the lines" as "remove the files". Is it actually what you want, or should I replace the `rm` invocations by some conditional printing of the lines toward an output file ?

Comment: I see now,  I just changed that one line myself to what i need: 
rm() { echo "Del \"""$@"; } 
(however ive been tweaking luciole75w's awk command below, as ideone.com was giving me trouble on changing the stdin data,  will update back here when done.  thank (i did do an upvote)